# Trouble with IF statement - Changing scenes with trigger + input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been trying to get this script to work for hours, which is much longer than I wanted to with something I thought would be simple.  I'm pretty new to Unity (although I've had a little bit of programming experience in the past).  I have a scene with a trigger, and when I hit the trigger I want it to enable a few UI elements (giving instructions to press a button) and when you press a key, it sends you to another scene.  What it's doing as is is it will enable the UI but doesn't load the scene when pressing the key assigned to Action.

Here's the script as is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class entryDining : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public GameObject uiPanel;
    public GameObject textBox;
    public string actionText;
    public string scene;


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        textBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = actionText;
        uiPanel.SetActive (true);
        textBox.SetActive (true);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D()
    {
        uiPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I've removed the if statement and just left the SceneManager and can walk into the trigger and it will send me to the scene I've set, so I've narrowed it down to the if statement isn't working as I'm intending.  Yet in the scene that I'm trying to have this script send me to I'm using this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class tempDining : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("entryWay");
        }
      
    }
}
```

and that's working just fine.  I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here =/  Help please!

Answer (score 0):

as per docs

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html

you can only call `Input.GetButtonDown` inside `Update`

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple I was missing, thank you so much!